# Trying to test validity of a sudoku puzzle: Having trouble with checking for duplicates in each 3x3 square

Tags: duplicates, sudoku

Here's my method:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicatesInSections(int[][] puzzle){

    z = 2;
    w = 0;
    while(z <= 8){ 
    for(i = w; i <= z; i++){
       for(j = w; j <= z; j++){
         for(l = w; l <= z; l++){   
            for(k = w; k <= z; k++){

             if ((puzzle[l][k] == puzzle[i][j]) && 
                 (puzzle[l][k] != 0)            &&
                 (k != j)){      

                 System.out.println("There was a match in a square. Shame on you.");
                 return true;   
             }
             }
             }
       }
       }
    z += 3;
    w += 3;
   }
    System.out.println("There wasn't a match in a square. Good job!");
    return false;
}
```

I made a 9x9 2-D int array for the puzzle. 0 means there's just a blank space. The method looks through each 3x3 square and says whether duplicates were found in one. But sometimes it still says there wasn't a match when there was. Can anybody see what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was wrong. All of my comparisons and iterations were correct except for when I checked:

```
 (k != j))
```

It was only checking if a column wasn't equal to a column which is wrong. So what I did is just add the indexes of the rows and columns and then compare them like so:

```
(l+k) != (i+j))
```

Which worked perfectly!